# How do I redirect the "No Result" search page to Add node?

Tags: search, redirection

I would like to redirect the "No result found" page of the drupal search to Add node. Basically I want when users search for an item using the search text box they get redirected to the Add node page when the item is not found.

Answer (score 1):

I was really hoping that `_preprocess_search_results(&$vars)` would work, but it only gets called when there are results, so, here are two really really I can't believe I am suggesting these but they should work ways:

Drupal 6:

In your theme's template.php file, you can retheme box, which is how drupal 6 creates the 'no results found' info:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_box($title, $content, $region = 'main') {

  if ($title==t('Your search yielded no results')) { 
    drupal_goto('node/add'); 
  } else {
    $output = '<h2 class="title">'. $title .'</h2><div>'. $content .'</div>';
    return $output;      
  }
}
```

If Drupal 7:

Copy `search-results.tpl.php` from the search module's directory to your theme directory and change it:

```
<?php if ($search_results): ?>
  <h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>
  <ol class="search-results <?php print $module; ?>-results">
    <?php print $search_results; ?>
  </ol>
  <?php print $pager; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php drupal_goto('node/add'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```