# Search box result => node add (searched string = node title)

Tags: search

What I want to achieve is quite simple, when performing a search trough the search block , instead of receiving the message "your search yielded no results" when the searched string is not in the DB I would like to have the possibility to add it as a node (question box "do you want to add yes or no?) , so the searched text would be the new node title.

[image: Example]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I redirect the "No Result" search page to Add node?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36644/how-do-i-redirect-the-no-result-search-page-to-add-node)

Comment: I don't think this is a dup.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of not indexing the content after adding it. You can re-index the site by visiting `http://<your-site-url>/admin/config/search/settings` and click "Re-index site".

[image: snap]

P.S: This will queue the items for re-indexing. The items will actually be re-indexed when "cron" runs for the next time (manually or scheduled cron job.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer. but the question was not how it comes that my searched text is not found, the question is how to have the second part of my image. having the possibilty to add the searched text (car) directly as a new node, i my case i want to use the searched text as node title.

Comment: @jurgenS I'm sorry to have misunderstood the question. You might need to see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/36652/6461 for your required answer.

Comment: Yes this is what i'm looking for, I am running D7 but don't quite understand the way to implement they describe in the provided link. the string should be posted automatically to the node add screen as the node title.